Fiancée’s Visa Application to Poland
My fiancée, who is a Polish citizen, will send me an invitation so I can apply for a visa. We have been together for three years, and I proposed to her this summer (she said yes!). However, after reading information from this sub and other sources, I am unsure if our "engagement" status will negatively affect our visa application.
We plan to meet in Krakow and have a romantic winter holiday in Zakopane. However, I have a few questions:
Should I write a letter and outline a detailed itinerary?
Should the visa application be based entirely on the length of our holiday, or is it possible to request a duration of 1-3 months?
Is it beneficial or detrimental to provide information about our relationship? If necessary, we can include photos from our three years together, especially those with the engagement ring.
Should the visa be a single-entry or multiple-entry visa?
Are there any other aspects I might have overlooked or need to pay attention to?
PS: I'm a Turkish Citizen if it matters!

The length of visa you apply for should match the length of time you plan to stay in Poland and the invitation from your fiancée, IMHO.

Do note that you can apply for a single entry visa and get a multi one, and vice versa. It's what you request, it's not what you get. I was issued a 8 day schengen visa as multi before when I applied as single entry, even when my itinerary made it clear that I had no plans to enter multiple times, and indeed, that'd be difficult with only 8 days.
